# Using request.user with Django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm having a problem with logged users and a Django `ModelForm`. I have a class named `_Animal_` that has a `ForeignKey` to `User` and some data related to the animal like age, race, and so on.

A user can add Animals to the db and I have to track the author of each animal, so I need to add the **request.user** that is logged when the user creates an animal instance.

**models.py**

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race)
    ...
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
```

The main goal is hide the publisher field in the form, and submit the logged user when hitting save button.

I can catch the current user in the view using `initial`, but what I also want is not display the field.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def new_animal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AnimalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
            return render_to_response('web/animal_form.html', variables)
    else:
        form = AnimalForm(initial={'publisher': request.user})
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
    return render_to_response('web/animal_form.html', variables)
```

Comment: Is the `User` an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You just need to exclude it from the form, then set it in the view.

```
class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        exclude = ('publisher',)
```

... and in the view:

```
    form = AnimalForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        animal = form.save(commit=False)
        animal.publisher = request.user
        animal.save()
```

(Note also that the first `else` clause - the lines immediately following the redirect - is unnecessary. If you leave it out, execution will fall through to the two lines at the end of the view, which are identical.)

Comment: can you please explain what is this line of code doing: `animal = form.save(commit=False)`?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for, yogeshiitm

Answer (score 9):

Another way (slightly shorter):
You need to exclude the field as well:

```
class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        exclude = ('publisher',)
```

then in the view:

```
animal = Animal(publisher=request.user)  
form = AnimalForm(request.POST, instance=animal)
if form.is_valid():
     animal.save()
```

Comment: This is a better answer. The `form.is_valid` here correctly calls the `models .clean()` and has access to the `publisher` field. In the other answer, the `publisher` field at that check would not yet be available, making it impossible to use DB `clean()` validation, and forcing the validation at the form level.

Answer (score 4):

I would add it directly to the form:

```
class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        exclude = ('publisher',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.publisher = self.request.user
        return super().save(commit=commit)
```

This is in my opinion the cleanest version and you may use the form in different views.

Comment: sadly this won't work (anymore?) because you can't access `self.request` in `ModelForm.save()`

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: It's Django 2.1 in this case

Comment: @melbic why is this giving an error: `'AnimalForm' object has no attribute 'request'`?...do i need to import something for it to work?

Comment: Maybe that's not working anymore in newer django versions. I probably used version 1.11 ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ModelAdmin
you should add method get form on your ModelAdmin

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BlogPostForm

    def get_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = super(BlogPostAdmin, self).get_form(request, **kwargs)
        form.request = request
        return from
```

and you can now access request in your ModelForm

```
class ProductAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def save(self, commit: bool,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().save(commit=commit)
        pass
```