# Django ModelForm: What is save(commit=False) used for?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

Why would I ever use `save(commit=False)` instead of just creating a form object from the `ModelForm` subclass and running `is_valid()` to validate both the form and model?

In other words, what is `save(commit=False)` for?

Can you provide hypothetical situations where this might be useful?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

That's useful when you get most of your model data from a form, but you need to populate some `null=False` fields with non-form data.

Saving with `commit=False` gets you a model object, then you can add your extra data and save it.

[This is a good example of that situation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575133/931277)

Here's the [documentation on the save method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). Note that if your form includes many-to-many fields, you'll also want to call `form.save_m2m()` after saving the model instance.

Comment: But then if this gets you a model object, how does it differ from assigning an previously instantiated object and assigning it to the ModelForm? (i.e `form = forms.SampleForm(instance = models.Sample)`)

Comment: Do you need `commit=False` if you are processing your form in a `CBV` with `def form_valid`? Can you just use `form.instance.[field]` to update?

Comment: Let's go to 100 :)

Comment: Yes, but: can you explain then why it is called a Django Antipatterns https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/using-commit-false-when-altering-the-instance-in-a-modelform.html. I am seeing this method called all over the place and not able to find good alternatives. thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Carlo . The Django docs still recommend the approach in this answer (I added a link), but it looks like the solution recommended by django-antipatterns would work as well.

Answer (score 54):

Here it is the answer ([from docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)):

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> f = AuthorForm(request.POST)

# Create, but don't save the new author instance.
>>> new_author = f.save(commit=False)
```

The most common situation is to get the instance from form but only 'in memory', not in database. Before save it you want to make some changes:

```
# Modify the author in some way.
>>> new_author.some_field = 'some_value'

# Save the new instance.
>>> new_author.save()
```

Comment: Do you need `commit=False` if you are processing your form in a `CBV` with `def form_valid`? Can you just use `form.instance.[field]` to update?

Answer (score 24):

From the Django docs:

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument,
> which accepts either True or False. If you call save() with `commit=False`,
> then it will return an object that hasn't yet been saved to the database.
>
> In this case, it's up to you to call save() on the resulting model instance.
> This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it,
> or if you want to use one of the specialized model saving options.
> commit is True by default.

It seems that save(`commit=False`) does create a model instance, which it returns to you. Which is neat for some post processing before actually saving it!

Answer (score 11):

As a "real example", consider a user model where the email address and the username are always the same, and then you could overwrite your ModelForm's save method like:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self):
        # Sets username to email before saving
        user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.username = user.email
        user.save()
        return user
```

If you didn't use `commit=False` to set the username to the email address, you'd either have to modify the user model's save method, or save the user object twice (which duplicates an expensive database operation.)

Comment: Do you need `commit=False` if you are processing your form in a `CBV` with `def form_valid`? Can you just use `form.instance.[field]` to update?

Answer (score 2):

The basic thing here I understand is that it changes from a 'form' instance to a particular 'model' instance in view.

Let suppose I want to post an answer like this in StackOverflow.
The code would be like this:

```
# Create a form instance with POST data.
>>> form_data = AnswerForm(request.POST)

# Create, but don't save the new answer instance.
>>> Answer = form_data.save(commit=False)
```

So now we have to add the owner of this answer and save this in our database in the view page like this:

```
>>> Answer.owner = request.user

>>> Answer.save()
```

So like this, we can add the owner of this answer which we cannot do like `form_data.owner = request.user` in the view page and also not in the form class.

So basically, it changes from 'form' instance to 'model' instance and then lets you to modify the data and save it.

Answer (score 1):

```
            form = AddAttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                attachment = form.save(commit=False)
                attachment.user = student
                attachment.attacher = self.request.user
                attachment.date_attached = timezone.now()
                attachment.competency = competency
                attachment.filename = request.FILES['attachment'].name
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.png','jpg','jpeg','.ai','.bmp','.gif','.ico','.psd','.svg','.tiff','.tif')):
                    attachment.file_type = "image"
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.mp4','.mov','.3g2','.avi','.flv','.h264','.m4v','.mpg','.mpeg','.wmv')):
                    attachment.file_type = "video"
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.aif','.cda','.mid','.midi','.mp3','.mpa','.ogg','.wav','.wma','.wpl')):
                    attachment.file_type = "audio"
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.csv','.dif','.ods','.xls','.tsv','.dat','.db','.xml','.xlsx','.xlr')):
                    attachment.file_type = "spreasheet"
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith(('.doc','.pdf','.rtf','.txt')):
                    attachment.file_type = "text"
                attachment.save()
```

here is my example of using save(commit=False). I wanted to check what type of file a user uploaded before saving it to the database. I also wanted to get the date it was attached since that field was not in the form.

Comment: this is a python code you can't run it in code snippet

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, here we update the form object and let them know that don't save the values in the database right now, we might change some input with instance and then use .save() to save all values in the database.

This gives us the flexibility to get all values from the HTML form and customize them according to our requirement and then save the instance.

Answer (score 0):

- [save(commit=False)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) cannot save objects but can return objects in a list and is used to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin. *As far as I researched and experimented, using `save(commit=False)` is the easiest way to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin.
- `save()` equivalent to `save(commit=True)` can save objects, then can retrun objects in a list and is not used to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin because more queries are run.

For example, there are `Category` model and `Product` model which has the foreign key of `Category` model as shown below:

```py
# "my_app/models.py"

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, there is overridden [save_formset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset) with `print(formset.save())` in `Category` admin which has `Product` inline as shown below. *`save_formset()` is run when changing inline objects:

```py
# "my_app/admin.py"

class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product
    extra = 0
    
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        print(formset.save()) # Here
```

And, there is `Fruits` category which has `Apple` and `Orange` products as shown below:

[image]

Now, I change `Apple` to `Apple Juice` and `Orange` to `Orange Juice` by clicking on **SAVE** as shown below:

[image]

Then, `Apple` is changed to `Apple Juice` and `Orange` is changed to `Orange Juice` as shown below:

[image]

Then, 2 inline objects are returned in a list on console as shown below:

```
[<Product: Apple Juice>, <Product: Orange Juice>]
```

And, two inline objects are saved by two `UPDATE` queries according to the PostgreSQL logs below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction#answer-73432601) explaining about how to log queries in PostgreSQL:

[image]

Next, I use `formset.save(commit=False)` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app/admin.py"

# ...

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        print(formset.save(commit=False)) # Here
```

Now again, I change `Apple` to `Apple Juice` and `Orange` to `Orange Juice` by clicking on **SAVE** as shown below:

[image]

Then, `Apple` is not changed to `Apple Juice` and `Orange` is not changed to `Orange Juice` as shown below:

[image]

Then, 2 inline objects are returned in a list on console as shown below:

```
[<Product: Apple Juice>, <Product: Orange Juice>]
```

Then, two inline objects are not saved by two `UPDATE` queries according to the PostgreSQL logs below:

[image]

Next, I make the submitted names of inline objects uppercase with `formset.save(commit=False)` as shown below. *Again, `save(commit=False)` is used to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin:

```py
# "my_app/admin.py"

# ...

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        for object in formset.save(commit=False): # Here
            object.name = object.name.upper()
        formset.save()
```

Now, I add `Vegetable` category, `Cucumber` and `Potato` products by clicking on **SAVE** as shown below:

[image]

Then, `Cucumber` and `Potato` are made uppercase as shown below:

[image]

And, two inline objects are saved by two `INSERT` queries according to the PostgreSQL logs below:

[image]

Next, I make the submitted names of inline objects uppercase with `formset.save()` as shown below. *Again, `save()` equivalent to `save(commit=True)` is not used to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin because more queries are run:

```py
# "my_app/admin.py"

# ...

@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProductInline,)

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        for object in formset.save(): # Here
            object.name = object.name.upper()
        formset.save()
```

Now again, I add `Vegetable` category, `Cucumber` and `Potato` products by clicking on **SAVE** as shown below:

[image]

Then again, `Cucumber` and `Potato` are made uppercase as shown below:

[image]

And first, two inline objects with `Cucumber` and `Potato` are saved by two `INSERT`, and second, two inline objects with `CUCUMBER` and `POTATO` are saved by two `UPDATE` queries according to the PostgreSQL logs below:

[image]

So, don't use `save()` to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin because more queries are run. Instead, you should use `save(commit=False)` to customize the submitted inline objects in Django Admin.