# right username password not login django

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am developing a small website with django and I am using the built-in login view. When I register a standard user and then try to login with the right credentials it shows me the login error "please enter a correct username and password". This problem doesn't occurr with the superusers that I created. The can login with the right credentials without any error message showed.

This is the views.py with my registration view.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import UserForm

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            return redirect('user_profile', pk=user.pk)
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'interport/register_user.html', {'form':form})
```

The admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password',)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register_user$', views.register_user, name='register_user'),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

the template for login:

```
{% extends "interport/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center col s4 offset-s4 card-panel #fff8e1 amber lighten-5">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: where are you trying to log in? the django admin view?  I'm pretty sure that only superusers have access to the admin view.

Comment: @deweyredman `is_admin` boolean gives a user access to the admin. Superusers have all permissions. But authentication is something else. It is perfectly okay to login a user that does not have access to the admin at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're saving the new user with a plain text password, but Django will always hash the password before checking for validity.

You need to create your users via `User.objects.create_user()`, which hashes the password correctly, or use `user.set_password()` to set the hashed password after creating.

Comment: so @daniel I should modify the view for registration and after:
    user= form.save()
put  this line:
    user.set_password('raw_password')

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good and old, however I would advice to put those instructions in the `save` function of the said form.
This way allows you to have a clearer code in your views and an easier maintenance should you change the way the form is handled. you dont have to go back to every function in your `views.py` where you used that form.

in OP's case, the Form would look like that afterwards:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username', 'password',)

    def save(self, commit=False):
        instance = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False) # create but don't save yet
        if commit:
            instance.set_password(instance.password)
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

There might be more elegant way, but it's been working for me like that.

to have explanation regarding commit=False : [Django ModelForm: What is save(commit=False) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for)