# Django not saving the Custom User as the foreign key in another model: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using a custom user model. I don't know for some reason it's not saving the user in the post table. (The user is actually the author of the blog)

Here is the error trace:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/create/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['authentica.apps.AuthenticaConfig',
 'post.apps.PostConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: post_posts.user_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\authen\post\views.py" in post
  27.                 form.save()

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  458.             self.instance.save()

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\hello\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /post/create/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: post_posts.user_id
```

Here are the files:

## models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published_time= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    title= models.CharField(blank=False, editable=True, max_length=255)
    myslug= models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank= True, null= True)
    updated= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank= True)
    content= models.CharField(default=False, max_length=255,editable=True)
```

NOTE: I've already tried putting default and null=True. But it sets Null or default in either cases in the user column.
I'll also provide the custom user model, just in case.

## models.py (Custom User)

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self,email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    # def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    #     extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    #     if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
    #         raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    #     return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')


    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin
```

## forms.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content= forms.CharField(widget= forms.Textarea)
    title= forms.CharField(label= None, widget=forms.TextInput())
    class Meta:
        model= Posts
        fields= ('content', 'title',)
```

## views.py

```
class PostView(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'post/bloginput.html'
    def get(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form= PostForm()
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
    def post(self, request):
        if request.POST:
            form= PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                content= form.cleaned_data.get('content')
                title= form.cleaned_data.get('title')
                print(content, title)
                form.save()
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form= PostForm()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

Comment: Could you share your PostForm?

Comment: I've added forms.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because your `Post` model requires a mandatory user and your `PostForm` does not provide this. If you want to add the current user and do not want to add this field to your form you need to add the `User` before finally saving your model. You could do the following

```
# Your other code

if form.is_valid():
    post = fom.save(commit=False)
    post.user = request.user
    post.save()

# more code
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) or in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for)