# Django - assign authenticated user to post (automatically)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making a little Twitter-like app that you can "tweet" in. I've already set up the logic to log in, log out, register and write new posts. But now, when a user is logged in, I want the username to be automatically assigned to the user who logged in.
models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300, default='')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class NewTweet(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ['image', 'text']
```

I only show the fields image and text. The created_at and user attributes should be filled in automatically. Now in my views.py I handle saving new posts (tweets):
views.py

```
@login_required
def newTweet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_tweet = NewTweet(request.POST)
        if new_tweet.is_valid():
            new_tweet.cleaned_data['user'] = request.user
            new_tweet.save()
            return redirect('homepage')
    else:
        new_tweet = NewTweet()
    return render(request, 'homepage/new-tweet.html', {
        'tweet': new_tweet
    })
```

I tried to assign the user via clean_data attr. and the request.user but that doesn't work and throws an error

> IntegrityError at /new-tweet NOT NULL constraint failed:
> homepage_tweet.user_id

Inside the html file I just paste `{{ tweet }}` inside a form tag. I knew that I got the right user because when I print request.user the logged in user is shown correct. Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`commit=False`**

```
@login_required
def newTweet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_tweet = NewTweet(request.POST)
        if new_tweet.is_valid():

            tweet = new_tweet.save(commit=False)
            tweet.user = request.user
            tweet.save()

            return redirect('homepage')
    else:
        new_tweet = NewTweet()
    return render(request, 'homepage/new-tweet.html', {
        'tweet': new_tweet
    })
```

**Reference:**

- [Django ModelForm: What is save(commit=False) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for)