# converting input value into negatives before saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Please I have the model and the view below but I want a situation in which any value entered in the quantity field would be saved as a negative number in my database.

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
    receiveform = ReceiveForm(request.POST or None)
    stockform = StockForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        if receiveform.is_valid() and stockform.is_valid():
            receiveform.save()
            stockform.save()
            messages.success(request,('Data save succefully'))
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
           print(receiveform.errors)

    receiveform = ReceiveForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
      'receiveform':receiveform,
      'stockform':stockform,
     
    }
    return render(request, 'storesapp/receives.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Receives(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=now)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify any model attributes before you actually save the form using [`commit=False`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848605/django-modelform-what-is-savecommit-false-used-for). Replace the following line

```
receiveform.save()
```

with this

```
receives_instance = receiveform.save(commit=False)
receives_instance = -abs(receives_instance.quantity)
receives_instance.save()
```

The `abs` will ensure that any negative value submitted by the user will not be accidentally converted to positive.