# In Django, how to add username to a Model automatically, when the Form is submitted by a logged in user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, many-to-one

In my Django app, I have defined a Many-to-one relationship using ForeignKey. **Now what I want is that when a logged-in user submits the `ListForm` then his `username` should automatically add to the `owner` field of the `ListModel`.** Currently when a user submits the form, `None` is being shown in the owner field, how can I add the username to the database along with the form?

**my models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ListModel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**my forms.py:**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ListModel
from django import forms


class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ['owner','task', 'completed']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it working ([my solution reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467248/13962648))

First, we need to exclude the `owner` field from the ModelForm in **forms.py:**

```
class ListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ListModel
        fields = ['task', 'completed']
        # instead of above line we can simply write: exclude = ['owner']
```

and in the **views.py:**

```
form = ListForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    task_list = form.save(commit=False)
    task_list.owner = request.user
    task_list.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

where instead of `task_list` we can use any variable & also note that after `task_list.save()` no need to do `form.save()` because it's already included in `task_list = form.save(commit=False)`

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the `form_valid()` method of the View and attach the current logged in user as an Owner.

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user   <------ This line will do the trick.
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't work for me, I was still getting `None` in the owner field. However, your solution did let me know that I have to override `form_valid()` and helped me to solve my issue. In case you are interested check out my answer below. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, It is right. The above form_valid method exists on the class based views.